# Problems with generating table in mySQL using Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

For a database which has the following form:

```
user_id  print_pages
--------------------
123        0
456       10
789        5
123        2
789        6
```

I'm trying to get a table which outputs the summation of each distinct key's print_pages values:

```
user_id  print_pages
--------------------
123        2
456        10
789        11
```

So far the following mySQL code has generated syntax errors, could someone please enlighten me as to why?

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(print_pages) AS Summation FROM `file_prints` GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: What is the syntax error you get?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECTÂ user_id, SUM(print_pages) AS Summation FROM `file_prints`
GROUP BY user' at line 1

Comment: That SQL works fine. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d9c7/2). Look closely at your error message. You have an extra character after 'SELECT'

Comment: That's very weird, looks like UnknownFury was right. The A character wasn't visible when I initially typed the full command, but I just hit backspace after SELECT and it finally worked. Thanks!